# WebGL Multi-Textured Cube

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, 3d, webgl

I need to texture a cube with different textures for each side, unless there is an advantage doing it by single side. This is my Vertex Shader:..

```
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 vertPosition;
attribute vec2 vertTexCoord;
attribute float aFace;
uniform mat4 mWorld;
uniform mat4 mView;
uniform mat4 mProj;

varying vec2 fragTexCoord;
varying float vFace;

void main()
{
  fragTexCoord = vertTexCoord;
  vFace = aFace;
  gl_Position = mProj * mView * mWorld * vec4(vertPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:..

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D front;
uniform sampler2D back;
uniform sampler2D top;
uniform sampler2D bottom;
uniform sampler2D right;
uniform sampler2D left;

varying vec2 fragTexCoord;
varying float vFace;

void main()
{
  if(vFace < 0.1)
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(front, fragTexCoord);
  else if(vFace < 1.1)
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(back, fragTexCoord);
  else if(vFace < 2.1)
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(top, fragTexCoord);
  else if(vFace < 3.1)
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(bottom, fragTexCoord);
  else if(vFace < 4.1)
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(right, fragTexCoord);
  else
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(left, fragTexCoord);
}totorials
```

Then before I start rendering this runs. (The variables are globally defined):..

```
cubeVertexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexBufferObject);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(cubeVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

cubeIndexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeIndexBufferObject);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(cubeIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

textureLookUpBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, textureLookUpBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(lookUpArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'vertPosition');
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionAttributeLocation,
    3,
    gl.FLOAT,
    gl.FALSE,
    5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    0
);

texCoordAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'vertTexCoord');
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    texCoordAttributeLocation,
    2,
    gl.FLOAT,
    gl.FALSE,
    5 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    3 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
);

textureLookUpAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aFace");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    textureLookUpAttribute,
    1,
    gl.FLOAT,
    false,
    0,
    0
);

faces.front = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"front");
faces.back = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"back");
faces.top = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"top");
faces.bottom = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"bottom");
faces.right = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"right");
faces.left = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"left");
//
cubeMatWorldUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'mWorld');
cubeMatViewUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'mView');
cubeMatProjUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'mProj');

worldMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
viewMatrix = new Float32Array(16);
projMatrix = new Float32Array(16);

mat4.identity(worldMatrix);
mat4.lookAt(viewMatrix, [0, 0, -8], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]);
mat4.perspective(projMatrix, glMatrix.toRadian(45), Canvas.width / Canvas.height, 0.1, 1000.0);

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(cubeMatWorldUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, worldMatrix);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(cubeMatViewUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, viewMatrix);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(cubeMatProjUniformLocation, gl.FALSE, projMatrix);
```

Finally every time I render this runs:..

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVertexBufferObject);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, textureLookUpBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(textureLookUpAttribute, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeIndexBufferObject);

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.uniform1i(faces.front, 0);

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, grass);
gl.uniform1i(faces.back, 1); 

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE2);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.uniform1i(faces.top, 2);

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE3);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, grass);
gl.uniform1i(faces.bottom, 3);

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE4);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.uniform1i(faces.right, 4);

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE5);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, grass);
gl.uniform1i(faces.left, 5);

gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 36, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

It gives me error messages. Their different when I changed the code slightly(When I was trying to fix it) so that why i don't have an exact error message. If you need the different arrays for the cube i can post them. I was fallowing online tutorials on how to do this(on in general) but obviously as you can see it didn't work.

Comment: If you want help on a specific error you need to post the error

Answer (score 3):

The most common way to texture a cube with a different face on each side is to use a [texture atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas). Put all the faces in 1 texture and use texture coordinates to select the right part of the texture for each face.

[See the bottom of this article](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html)

The advantages are there's 1 texture. 1 texture unit to setup. 1 uniform to set. More samplers left for other things (normal maps, etc..) A simple shader that runs faster.